# preg_replace words with @

Tags: php, regex

Trying to use preg_replace to find words with @ in them and replace the whole word with nothing.

```
<?php

$text = "This is a text @removethis little more text";

$textreplaced = preg_replace('/@*. /', '', $text);

echo $captions;
```

Should output: This is a text little more text

Been trying to google on special charc and such but am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\w`:

```
$textreplaced = preg_replace('/@[\w]+ /', '', $text);
echo $textreplaced;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Only finding one at character at a time

I believe you are only finding the '@' to begin with, but if you find the whole string inside use `\b` around the regex so your final regex should be something like `/(@).{2,}?\b/`.

**The ? mark is important because regexes are greedy and grab as many letters as posible**

> Just a tip visit a tester like [regexpal](http://regexpal.com)